# Issue on image with href style

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to  create `href` over image like on image below.I have no exact idea how to set it.I have tried code like this but didn't work.Here Submit your prayer will be link in red color.My code  is :

```
<div class="col-md-4">
<img src="images/prayer.jpg" />
<a class="pray" href="a.com">Submit your prayer request</a>
</div>
```

[refrence image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ye30T.png)

[image]

Comment: Put your attempted version of the above into a JSFiddle so it will be easier for people to figure out what you are doing wrong https://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You achieve this by positioning the link absolutely over the image (added some more CSS to fit the image inside `.col-md-4`, roughly translates to what Bootstrap does):

```css
.col-md-4
{
    position: relative;
}

.col-md-4 a
{
    background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.3);
    bottom: 0;
    padding: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
}

.col-md-4 img
{
    display: block;
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-4">
    <img src="http://dummyimage.com/300x150/cccccc/fff" />
    <a class="pray" href="a.com">Submit your prayer request</a>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/maryisdead/378yuxsa/)

Answer (score 1):

if you want your image has a href link so when ever anyone click on your image that should take them to the link you want as like a link on text so make a small change in your code,

just wrap your  tag on  tag like bellow.

```
<div class="col-md-4">
<a class="pray" href="a.com"><img src="images/prayer.jpg" />Submit your prayer request</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks but i want a separate link shown on image on red color.not complete image as href.

Answer (score 1):

You must just add anchor ("a") tag before image, so image must be inside anchor tag. I hope it helped.
Or do you want to use javascript for it?

If you want to separate:

```
<div class="col-md-4">
    <a href="anywhere">
     <img src="images/prayer.jpg" />
    </a>
    <a class="pray" href="a.com">Submit your prayer request</a>
 </div>
```

Comment: @AtifKhan so add class there.

Answer (score 1):

Make the containing `div` position absolute, so the `a` tag can be positioned absolute within the confines of the containing `div`

Something like:

```
<div class="col-md-4" style='position:absolute;'>
    <img src="images/prayer.jpg" />
    <a class="pray" href="a.com" style="background:rgba(255,0,0,0.7);position:absolute;right:0px;bottom:0px;">Submit your prayer request</a>
</div>
```

Comment: `.col-md-4` most likely stems from Bootstrap and applying  `position: absolute` to the column will break the layout. Besides, `position: relative` has the same effect.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using css property "`position: absolute;`". Appropriate css setup allows you to place href anchor where ever you want.

```
    <div class="col-md-4">
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ye30T.png" />
<a class="pray" style="position: absolute;
left: 68px;
top: 156px;
display: block;
width: 262px;
height: 48px;
padding-top: 12px;
padding-left: 21px;" href="a.com"></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<style>
  img 
   {
   position: absolute;
   z-index: -1;
   }
</style>

<div class="col-md-4">
   <img src="images/prayer.jpg" />
   <a class="pray" href="a.com">Submit your prayer request</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think need to use `area tag`, Click [here](http://jsfiddle.net/92Lzj978/) to see how it's work on your image.

```
<div class="col-md-4">
    <img src="images/prayer.jpg" width="322" height="195" usemap="#prayermap" />
    <map name="prayermap">
        <area shape="rect" coords="60,150,322,195" alt="Submit prayer request" href="a.com">
    </map>
</div>
```

Comment: That's a little bit overkill, no? Also doesn't play very nicely with responsive layouts.

Comment: @maryisdead He wants to red part of image be a link, you add link over image. I'm pretty sure your answer is not what he wants.

Comment: That _may_ be. And if so, delivering the image complete with the link visual rendered on it would be a pretty bad design choice as this can easily achieved with CSS only. Anyways, I think the image reference is just what OP wants it to look like.